# is it possible for multiple NSManagedObjectContext share same NSManagedObjectModel? and same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator instance

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject

Or put in another way, would it be suggested to have separate stack (context, model, coordinator) for different context? what's the pros and cons of separating them, and what's the pros and cons of having different context share the same model and coordinator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is quite acceptable for multiple contexts to share the same coordinator, model, etc. It's a very common usage pattern.

Since you didn't say why you thought it might not be, or what problems you're running into (if any), I'll just leave it at that.

Comment: can those multiple contexts be on the same thread? I am encountering a very weird issue. for the data saved by one context, when getting read via another context, I am getting empty data.

Comment: Yes, they can be on the same thread. Looks like you should start a new question with more details.